# I have a problem in connecting docker mysql with fastapi

Tags: python, mysql, docker, fastapi

When I run this command

> uvicorn app.main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 --reload

I get this error

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '0.0.0.0' ([WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context)")
> (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)

below two commands, both work without any errors:

> uvicorn app.main:app --host 127.0.0.1 --port 8000 --reload

> uvicorn app.main:app --host localhost --port 8000 --reload

Only 0.0.0.0 doesn't work.
I've tried to solve it, but now I'm asking you to take a look at this.
Thanks.

This is Docker image run code

> docker run -d --name fastapi-db -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=1234 -e MYSQL_DATABASE=dev -e MYSQL_USER=admin -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=1234 mysql:8.0 --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

```
# models.py

from sqlalchemy import Boolean, Column, Integer, String

from .database import Base

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(String(255), unique=True, index=True)
    password = Column(String(255))
    is_active = Column(Boolean, default=True)
```

```
# database.py

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker


engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://admin:1234@0.0.0.0:3306/dev")
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(
    bind=engine,
    autocommit=False,
    autoflush=False,
)

Base = declarative_base()
```

```
# schemas.py

from pydantic import BaseModel


class UserBase(BaseModel):
    email: str


class UserCreate(UserBase):
    password: str


class User(UserBase):
    id: int
    email: str
    is_active: bool

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

```
# main.py

from typing import List

from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI, HTTPException
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

from . import models, schemas
from .database import SessionLocal, engine

models.Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)


app = FastAPI()


def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()


@app.post("/users", response_model=schemas.User)
def create_user(user: schemas.UserCreate, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    existed_user = db.query(models.User).filter_by(
        email=user.email
    ).first()

    if existed_user:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Email already registered")

    user = models.User(email=user.email, password=user.password)
    db.add(user)
    db.commit()

    return user


@app.get("/users", response_model=List[schemas.User])
def read_users(db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    return db.query(models.User).all()
```

[docker image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SLUP.png)

[image: docker image inspect]

[image: Resource Monitor 3306 port]

[image: TCPView =3306 / =0]

Comment: please read this post https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question and edit your question

Answer (score 1):

Try:

engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://admin:1234@**localhost**:3306/dev")

Comment: That is probably wrong in a Docker context (though more meaningful than `0.0.0.0`, "everywhere").  Without seeing any actual code or configuration in the question it's a little tricky to tell though.

Comment: Thanks. 'localhost ' instead of '0.0.0.0' actually works. But I still wonder why 0.0.0.0 wouldn't work?

Comment: How can you connect to "everywhere"? Obviously, that's not gonna work if you use it to connect.